# Good HIDS for Windows?

Tags: windows, security

Is there a free Host-based Intrusion Detection System (HIDS) software that I can use for Windows? I want it for my PC at home.

I'm currently running Windows 10 Pro, for those interested.

I guess the more obvious question would be as to why I would want/need one. I would answer that but I feel it would eventually detract from the main question.

Mainly what I'm looking for:

- Something free (however, can include premium versions).
- Something with a well-off GUI that has intuitive UI
  which enables easy learning.
- Doesn't have to be open-source (although
  I'd imagine most free options are).
- Something light-weight AND
  something that's compatible with AVG.

EDIT:
In the end, what you find might not fit all of these requirements, but I guess what makes more sense here is something that I can run easily in the background without too much trouble.
I just need something that will compliment AVG, if that makes any sense.

Comment: It might be helpful to include what areas you want covered (what are the must-haves), as well as what your price limit is.

Comment: @Izzy Good advice, I will include that.

Comment: That would be good. Better do it sooner than later ;) Pointer: you can [edit] your post ;)